# How to find the largest blank(white) square area in the doc and return its coordinates and area?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, document

I need to find the largest empty area in the document and display its coordinates, center point and area, using python to put a QR Code there.
I think OpenCV and Numpy should be enough for this task.

- What kinda THRESH to use? Because there are a lot of types of scans:
  gray, BW, with color, and how to find the contour properly?
- How this can be implemented in the fastest way? An example using the
  first scan from google is attached, where you can see that the code
  should find the largest empty square area.
  [image: square]

@Mark Setchell Thanks! This code works perfectly for all docs with a white background, but when I use smth with a color in the background it finds a completely different area. Also, to keep thin lines in the docs I used Erode after thresholding. Tried to change thresholding and erode parameters, still not working properly.
Edited post, added color pictures.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Odd-shape squares in your part of the world ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell its just an example :)

Comment: It can be annoying for people who are answering when the question is ambiguous or the sample images are not representative because you waste time based on incorrect assumptions. Your title asks to find largest area (no shape specified), your text asks for a square and your diagram shows a rectangle - at least 2 very different questions/answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

def largestSquare(im): 
    # Make image square of 100x100 to simplify and speed up
    s = 100
    work = cv2.resize(im, (s,s), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

    # Make output accumulator - uint16 is ok because...
    # ... max value is 100x100, i.e. 10,000 which is less than 65,535
    # ... and you can make a PNG of it too
    p = np.zeros((s,s), np.uint16)
  
    # Find largest square
    for i in range(1, s): 
        for j in range(1, s): 
            if (work[i][j] > 0 ): 
                p[i][j] = min(p[i][j-1], p[i-1][j], p[i-1][j-1]) + 1
            else: 
                p[i][j] = 0

    # Save result - just for illustration purposes
    cv2.imwrite("result.png",p)

    # Work out what the actual answer is
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(p, axis=None), p.shape)
    print(f'Location: {ind}')
    print(f'Length of side: {p[ind]}')
      
# Load image and threshold
im  = cv2.imread('page.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, thr = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Get largest white square
largestSquare(thr)
```

**Output**

```
Location: (21, 77)
Length of side: 18
```

[image]

**Notes:**

1. I edited out your red annotation so it didn't interfere with my algorithm.
2. I did Otsu thresholding to get pure black and white - that may or may not be appropriate to your use case. It will depend on your scans and paper background etc.
3. I scaled the image down to 100x100 so it doesn't take all day to run. You will need to scale the results back up to the size of your original image but I assume you can do that easily enough.

**Keywords**: Image processing, image, Python, OpenCV, largest white square, largest empty space.

Comment: Hey Mark, you posted this years ago and I've just come across it. It has been really helpful for me and seems to work really well. One issue I've had though is that when running your program with OP's original image,, result.png is just a black square. It doesn't look anything like the output accumulator result image you posted. Do you have any ideas why that might be? Thanks :)